# Why won't this code recognize any of the if statements?

Tags: c

My program takes all data and asks if you would like it displayed in 3 different ways. CSV, TSV, XML. I added 2 if statements and when trying to get them to work it will ask for me to choose which setting I want displayed then it will end the program. Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int  phoneNumber;
    char firstName[11];
    char lastName[11];
    char eMail[20];
    int output;
    int CSV;
    int TSV;
    int XML;

    printf("Please enter the user's first name:");
    scanf("%s", firstName);
    printf("Please enter the user's last name:");
    scanf("%s", lastName);
    printf("Please enter the user's phone number:");
    scanf("%i", &phoneNumber);
    printf("Please enter the user's e-mail:");
    scanf("%s", eMail);
    printf("What output format would you like? (CSV,TSV/XML) ");
    scanf("%d", &output);

    if (output == 'CSV') {
        printf("firstName,lastName,phoneNumber,eMail");
        printf("%s,%s,%i,%s",firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, eMail);
    }
    else if (output == 'TSV') {
        printf("firstName,\tlastName,\tphoneNumber,\teMail");
        printf("%s,\t%s,\t%i,\t%s", firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, eMail);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, as mentioned, you need to use the `strcmp` function to compare strings.  `==` is testing whether the string is in the same place as the constant the compiler generated, which it won't be.

```
#include <string.h>
```

and then you can use

```
if(strcmp(output,"CSV")==0) { /*output CSV*/ }
```

Second, you need to use `"` rather than `'` to delimit strings; `'` is for single characters only.

Third, the `CSV` and `TSV` variables are never given values.  Use

```
char output[256];
scanf("%s", output)
```

and then you can use `strcmp(output, "CSV")` (or `strcasecmp` depending on whether you want case-sensitivity).

Answer (score 3):

here are the changes you need to make:

```
   printf("What output format would you like? (CSV,TSV/XML) ");
   scanf("%s", &output);
   ...


   if (strcmp(output, "CSV") == 0) {
   // ...
   } else if (strcmp(output, "TSV") == 0) {
   // ...
   }
```

Comment: but output is an `int`

Comment: of course output has to be defined as a string

Answer (score 2):

#### In C you perform string equality checks with [`strcmp(...)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Additionally, string literals must be enclosed with quotation marks `"`.

```c
#include <string.h>
// ...
if (strcmp(output, "CSV") == 0) {
  // ...
} else if (strcmp(output, "TSV") == 0) {
  // ...
}
```

**[Edit]** If you are trying to use integers to represent those values (CSV, TSV, XML) then you should do something like this:

```c
const int CSV = 1;
const int TSV = 2;
const int XML = 3;
// ...
printf("What output format would you like? (CSV=1,TSV=2,XML=3) ");
scanf("%d", &output);
// ...
if (output == 1/*CSV*/) {
  // ...
} else if (output == 2/*TSV*/) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @highlycaffeinated where are those ints initialized?

Answer (score 1):

```
int output;
/* ... */
printf("What output format would you like? (CSV,TSV/XML) ");
scanf("%d", &output);
```

You ask the user to enter `CSV`, `TSV`, or `XML`, but then you read an *integer*, which to be valid must be an optional `+` or `-` followed by a sequence of decimal digits.

```
if (output == 'CSV') {
```

`'CSV'` is a multi-character constant. It's of type `int`, and it has an *implementation-defined* value. That value has nothing to do with whatever the user entered at the previous prompt.

(It's unfortunate that this compiles without error. Multi-character constants are nearly useless.)

You can assign numbers to `CSV`, `TSV`, and `XML`, show the user those numbers, read numeric input, and then compare it. For example:

```
const int CSV = 1;
const int TSV = 2;
const int XML = 3;
printf("What output format would you like? (CSV,TSV/XML) ");
scanf("%d", &output); /* error checking omitted for now */
if (output == CSV) {
    /* ... */
}
else if (output == TSV) {
    /* ... */
}
/* ... */
```

Or you can change `output` to a character or a string, read that (using the appropriate `scanf` format), and then compare `output` to a character or to a string.

Note that if you go with strings, you'll need to use `strcmp()`, not `==`, to compare them.

And be sure to check the value returned by `scanf`. It returns the number of items it was able to scan. For the calls you're using, if `scanf` returns something other than 1, it means there was an error of some sort (for example the user typed `foo` when you were expecting an integer), and you need to report the error and probably quit the program -- or perhaps use a loop to continue prompting the user until you get something valid.